# define alternate version of python function using different libraries / global vars

Tags: python, function, global, libraries

I am using both python `numpy` and the `jax.numpy` replacement for numpy and I often need some user-defined function for both. The issue is that `jax.numpy` is such a good drop-in replacement that very often I'm essentially writing the same function for both libraries. So to give a very simple example I might have:

**module_numpy.py**:

```
import numpy as np

def get_loss(x):
    return np.square(x) + 1
```

**module_jax.py**:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp

def get_loss(x):
    return jnp.square(x) + 1
```

where I basically write the same code twice, and the problem is that **if I make a change to either one of these functions, I have to make the same change to both, and it becomes a lot to maintain**. I may come back to functions I've changed later and not realize which one is the most "correct" or more recently updated.

**Question**: How can I essentially redefine a library by replacing the global variables under which `module_numpy.get_loss` is defined? For instance, I have tried:

**module_jax_auto.py**:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import module_numpy
import inspect

f = eval(inspect.source(module_numpy.get_loss).replace('np', 'jnp'))
```

but python complains with a syntax error. Apparently I can't used `def` inside eval, but even if I could, I'm not sure this is the "best" way solve the issue of maintain 2 parallel libraries. But I do always want to use the `numpy` version to define the `jax` version, and not the other way around.

It's worth nothing that there are some cases where I do need to define the `jax` version of the function differently, so I will exclude some functions from being "auto-generated" from the numpy version.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: Can you define all your functions in a class and then pass np as a parameter or define a global within a module which is assigned to the version of numpy outside the module

Comment: Defining all these functions feels like a hack to me because the vast majority of this code is stateless. Defining an external global doesn't really work if I'm understanding your comment correctly, since I need to be able to use both functions in the same runtime and not just one or the other.

Comment: If the code for both libraries the same or is it just the function names?

Comment: Yes they are in vast majority of cases the same exact code as in the example above, just with `jnp` instead of `np`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by it feels like a hack.  If it gets you to where you want, does it matter whether it is a hack or not.

```
import numpy as np
import jax.numpy as jnp

# Replecated functions
class ncommon:
    def __init__(me, np):
        me.np = np

    def get_loss(me, x):
        return me.np.square(x) + 1

# Specific function for np
class SNP(ncommon):
    def __init__(me):
        ncommon.__init__(me, np)

    def get_profit(me, x):
        return me.np.square(x) + 2

# Specific functions for jnp
class JNP(ncommon):
    def __init__(me):
        ncommon.__init__(me, jnp)

    def get_profit(me, x):
        return me.np.square(x) + 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    snpy = SNP()
    jnpy = JNP()
    print(f'common   {snpy.get_loss(4)}    {jnpy.get_loss(4)}')
    print(f'specific {snpy.get_profit(4)}  {jnpy.get_profit(4)}')
```

Alternatively, if you are dead against using classes, just pass in the version of numpy as a parameter.

```
def get_loss(np, x):
    return np.square(x) + 1

print(f'std {get_loss(np, 5)}  jax {get_loss(jnp, 5)}')
```